# Does an Itô process belong to L2ad(ΩX[0,T]) in any cases?

Tags: vector-spaces, stochastic-processes

Does an Itô process belong to L2ad(ΩX[0,T]) in any cases ?
Someone could tell me whether this is right or not and why. Because I know from my stochastic process studies that the sigma part of the Itô process has to belong to Lad(Ω;L2([0,T]), so I wonder if this implies that the whole Itô process belonging to L2ad(ΩX[0,T]) or not. My doubts come from the lectures because in many exercises my professor consider the Itô process belonging to L2ad(ΩX[0,T]) without demonstrating it.